# Which speed should I use with cdrecord on a DVD?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, dvd-burning

When using cdrecord for data (not audio) to a DVD, should I just say speed=-1?  Does slower speed (like speed=1) make for more reliable recording, or longer shelf life?  What are the tradeoffs?  What speed= parameter should I use, and why?

Comment: At higher speeds there _can_ be some corruption. It has never happened to me personally; then again, I never really bother with altering the recording speed. Burning at higher speeds (i.e. speeds higher than the DVDs rated speed) _can_ lower the reflectivity of the recording surface to a point where the reading laser will not reflect accurately. Therefore the data read is inaccurate/corrupt. If I really understood the physics I, would have posted an answer.

Comment: I also don't have a scientific answer but recording at lower speeds seems to have less failure rates and longer shelf life. Just personal experience and observation. I usually record at half speed of the maximum drive speed.